# Any reasons to keep logging?

Tags: logging

You can disable logging in the admin as well as in `local.xml` so writing to the DB is completely stopped. See this for more info: http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/ . I know some large-volume sites that have logging disabled completely.

Is there any reason, other than being the admin's reference, to keep any logging (`log_*` and/or `report_*` data) at all?

Comment: log data is useful for site analytics, to know from where you are getting users, which are most visited urls on website etc..

Comment: @huzefam That is not the logs the question is referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are in fact reasons that I would not recommend to disable all these.

At least the predispatch ones should NOT be disabled, i.e.

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
    <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
<controller_action_postdispatch>
    <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch>
```

I did this on a production system ones and it lead to errors with regards to the user's  compare products functionality.

The problem was that the pre and postdispatch logs generate IDs for guests. When deactivated, that ID is always 0 and thus, when a user adds something to the compare list, all guest IDs 0 are assigned to his user ID making the compare products functionality useless for all others.

It seems that the other logs can be disabled without impairing functionality.

Comment: Hm, good point. Disabling those two observers renders the compare item unfunctional for guests. It still works for logged users, however, using `customer_id` it seems.

Comment: Are you familiar with cleaning up any of the report_* tables? These are affected by `Mage_Report`, which hooks onto an event fired by `Mage_Log`, but the problem is that guest data seem to be left alone when the cleaning takes places, leading to a ton of old and probably useless data.